# Approximate a smooth f(x,y) function with a polynomial function

Tags: algorithms, approximation, polynomials

I have a discrete function of two real variables defined as a set of point in a rectangular domain. The function is smooth. I need to approximate it with a polynomial function of the 2nd degree with the error as little as possible. What algorithm can I use to find out the constants for the polynomial?

Comment: Your question confuses me a bit. Do you have a function that maps two real variables to a set of points? Is the domain of your function a rectangle in 2D space? How can a discrete function be smooth? Is it actually a function in the mathematical sense or rather some kind of curve? Maybe it would be helpful to elaborate on the signature of your function and what you mean with smooth.

Comment: @Mr Tsjolder, I have a function that maps real (x, y) values to another real value z. And yes, you can represent it as a surface in 3D space.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia:

> In statistics, polynomial regression is a form of regression analysis in which the relationship between the independent variable $x$ and the dependent variable $y$ is modelled as an $n^{th}$ degree polynomial in $x$.

One possible solution is the polynomial regression, that is, curve fitting method. Given a set of points $Y$ you may use one of two algorithms: [closed form solution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPolynomial.html) or [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent). When number of points is very large then the gradient descent is  faster than closed form solution. Also note that we measure error using residual sum of squares (RSS). Both algorithms finds coefficients by minimizing the RSS. [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23128/solving-for-regression-parameters-in-closed-form-vs-gradient-descent) may help as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have 2 independent variables x, y and one dependent variable z.

Comment: Linear regression works for any number of variables. Independent variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$ are treated as $n$ dimensional vectors and $y = f(< x_1,\dots x_n >)$. In your case $x_1 = x, x_2 = y$.

Comment: Also [segmented regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_regression) might be useful, if the surface would be too complex to be modelled by a single 2nd degree polynomial...